# how to work with for loop and if in NumPy lib in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

good evening.
i wanted to iterate an array and delete its indexes every other.
or maybe put those indexes i want in a new array.

I tried

```
Processed_Data=np.array([i for i in Engleashed_Serch_Results if (i%2)])
```

but there is an unsupported operand type(s) error on division.

Engleashed_Serch_Results is another NumPy array

Comment: What is `Engleashed_Serch_Results`?

Comment: Try `Processed_Data=np.array([Engleashed_Serch_Results[i] for i in range(len(Engleashed_Serch_Results)) if not (i % 2)])`.

Comment: @GodIsOne; im sorry for my terrible naming. `Engleashed_Serch_Results` is an other numpy array

Comment: @MattPitkin;i tried your code but thats not working currect,there is about 160 values in my  `Engleashed_Serch_Results` but in "Processed_Data" there is just 36.but there should be about 80.

Comment: What shape is your `Engleashed_Serch_Results` array? I was assuming it was 1-dimensional, in which case my code should work fine. Also, a much simpler version of my answer would be to use [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1862861) and do `Processed_Data = Engleashed_Serch_Results[::2]` (again, provided the data is 1d).

Comment: @MattPitkin it is one dimensional  but there is some fields empty next to each other i think this made problem because in this part it left all other indexes empty. my `Engleashed_Serch_Results` looks like:[... "2400000" , "4600000" , "11000000" , "<null>" , "<null>" , "<null>" , "38000" ...]

Comment: @MattPitkin, the slicing is not working too, even gave it start and stop point but it gives up when it recives null or 0 for seveal times

Comment: Could you provide the output of `print(Engleashed_Serch_Results.shape)` and `print(Engleashed_Serch_Results.dtype)`?

Comment: @MattPitkin this is what it prints for those two lines:`(165,)
<U32`first shape second dtype

Comment: The `"<null>"` are just being held as strings, so should not effect things. I've really no idea why the slicing is not working for you. If I just do something simple like: `import numpy as np; x = ["sadkjkbfd lldjaslhd asdjh sdalhd"]; a = np.array(165 * x)`, which produces an array with shape `(165,)` and type `<U32`, then slicing works as expected. If I replace some values with "<null>", it also works fine too.

Comment: "<null>" i means "" not any thing inside it. idont know but thank you i solved it  actualy i deleted all "" an then iserted two 0 s in array.... i know its not the right way to do it but its efffective :/